# Git how to partial merge files from another branch

Tags: git, merge

On branch brA:
topfolder/
-- fileA
-- folderA/
....
-- folderZ/

On branch brB:
topfolder/
-- fileA
-- folderA/
....
-- folderZ/

Suppose I am on brA, I want to merge all the files in brB other than fileA and create a new commit of brB.
That's, the new commit should contain the original brA/fileA, and all files of brB except brB/fileA.
How can I ahieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use git merging strategies.
I haven't used it personally but sounds like the right thing.

http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Merge-Strategies

Hope it helps.

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

So you want to merge everything except what is in one file.  This is a bit tedious but should work:

```
$ git checkout -b brB-wo-fileA brB
$ git checkout <commit before changes to fileA> -- fileA
$ git commit -m 'brB-w-fileA-reverted' -- fileA
$ git checkout brA
$ git merge brB-wo-fileA
```

and then you could finish it off with

```
$ git branch -d brB-wo-fileA
```

Regarding the `<commit before changes to fileA>`, you might find that with (no promises):

```
$ git merge-base brA brB
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing might be better served with

```
git checkout brA -- fileA
git commit -m "copy fileA from brA@$(git rev-parse --short brA)"
```

which produces

> the original brA/fileA, and all files of brB except brB/fileA

everything about the result you're after without advertising it as a merge.

If for some reason it's important to have a recorded merge there, the simplest method is

```
git checkout brB
git merge -s ours --no-commit brA
git checkout brA -- fileA

git commit -m 'just fileA from brA'
```

which will do it, but it's important to highlight that doing that merge marks the entire history of brA to date as merged, so no future merge will incorporate anything from brA up to that point, i.e.

```
...X---B---M     brB
          /
  ...Y---A       brA
```

the merge commit M shows the entire history of A and B as properly merged.  If you later wanted any other changes from A's history you'd have to hunt them down yourself and cherry-pick them.

---

Now: to be excruciatingly accurate in your history-keeping, you can isolate the changes to fileA in the history, by doing

```
git checkout $(git merge-base brA brB)
git checkout brA -- fileA
git commit -m "brA changes to fileA as of brA@$(git rev-parse brA --short)"
git tag wip

git checkout brB
git merge wip -m "brA:fileA"
git checkout brA
git merge wip -m "Identical to previous, recording separately-merged fileA"
git tag -d wip
```

which will produce

```
Z---o...X---B---B+fAA     brB   # merge of fileA as of commit A
|\             /
| \-----------(fAA)             # fileA as of commit A
|              \
 \---...Y---A---A'        brA   # A' identical to A, recording separate fileA merges
```

and anybody reading that (including `git merge`) will be able to determine exactly and unambiguously what happened.  But it's unusual enough (and useful so rarely) that doing it this way is likely to confuse people who don't really understand history graphs, so any downstream conflict, even one that doesn't involve fileA, might cause unnecessary consternation.